# im receivin an redirect uri mismatch when using oauth2 google

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-developers-console

Good day

I've been trying to set oauth2 using springBoot and authentication through google account. However, after setting everything in local and test correct functionality, it fails when i tried to test on server.

i have been receiving "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch", but not aditional information is being shown
[image: Error received]

Also, as authentication worked on local, i just added url's to server on google app

[image: myserverurl(not real in picture) aims to my server]

as its shown, url's to redirect are added, and i dont know what else to try. Anyone knows why? i will really appreciate the help

Comment: in Authorized redirect URIs, i've also tried with specific port 8080 and got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 stages of your deployment pipeline here:

- Developer local PC
- Deployed environment

In the deployed environment, this is happening:

- Your are redirecting on http://myserverurl:8080
- Google is selecting the first redirect URI to return the login response on
- This is http://localhost:8080, leading to the error

The preferred way to resolve your problem is to ensure that you create multiple OAuth client entries in the Authorization Server console, all with independent settings and a single / consistent host name:

- MyWebApp (DeveloperLocalPC)
- MyWebApp (DeployedTestEnvironment)
- MyWebApp (DeployedProductionEnvironment)

Comment: thank you so much, never thought google worked like that, this solved my issue :)